# Phonotaxis and Preference

Tags: zoology, ecology, ethology

(Am I losing my mind?) I could have sworn there was solid research indicating that phonotaxis evidence for preferences (during ex situ experiments) was "held up" by en situ experiments...(by this I mean lab experiments were replicated in wild populations).

Does anyone have, ideally, a peer reviewed article (honestly even a thesis will do at this point) showing that preferences among animals for certain other individuals (shown via phonotaxis) have some sort of real world, in-habitat related replication? Surely there is some reason/real world application as to why we do so many phonotaxis experiments in ecology. (Phototaxis is fine too by the way). What am I missing here? Anyway even something tangential could help me so please don't hesitate to reply to this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3929774/, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003347206003939, https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/501376, etc. Depending on what you mean, of course- some of this is wild populations and some of it is field experiments, not totally sure what you're going for. I found this stuff by literally googling "phonotaxis field experiments" and "phonotaxis wild population". Possibly more details would help to see why the abundant studies that I find aren't what you want.